# Python PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, permissions

My code is upload video to facebook using Graph API, It was uploading successfully, but after upload, iam getting error when iam trying to delete the video

```
import requests
videoTitle = 'Title of the post'
videoDesc = 'some xyz desc'
excel_path = fr'Output/Social/Facebook API.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_path)
pageID = df['PageID'].tolist()[0]
access_token = df['Access Token'].tolist()[0]
url = f'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v17.0/{pageID}/videos'
try:
    vidFile = r"Output/ImagestoVideo/1616 Mackinac Dr. Crowley.mp4"
    files = {'source': open(vidFile, 'rb')}
    payload = {
        'access_token': access_token,
        'title': videoTitle,
        'description': videoDesc,
    }
    response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=payload, verify=False).json()
    files['source'].close()
    video_id = response['id']
    if video_id:
        print(f'https://www.facebook.com/{pageID}/videos/{video_id}')
except:
    pass


os.remove(r"Output/ImagestoVideo/1616 Mackinac Dr. Crowley.mp4")
```

This is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\My Work\Drake YT Shorts\test3.py", line 92, in <module>
    os.remove(r"Output/ImagestoVideo/1616 Mackinac Dr. Crowley.mp4")
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'Output/ImagestoVideo/1616 Mackinac Dr. Crowley.mp4'
```

I am closing the file `files['source'].close()` after upload, but that doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you give this a try without the try/except blocks? In testing I was only able to reproduce this error if the upload failed, which would cause the script to jump to the except block bypassing the file close statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@1adog1 given solution works for me.

```
import requests
videoTitle = 'Title of the post'
videoDesc = 'some xyz desc'
excel_path = fr'Output/Social/Facebook API.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_path)
pageID = df['PageID'].tolist()[0]
access_token = df['Access Token'].tolist()[0]
url = f'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v17.0/{pageID}/videos'
vidFile = r"Output/ImagestoVideo/1616 Mackinac Dr. Crowley.mp4"
files = {'source': open(vidFile, 'rb')}
try:
    
    payload = {
        'access_token': access_token,
        'title': videoTitle,
        'description': videoDesc,
    }
    response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=payload, verify=False).json()
    video_id = response['id']
    if video_id:
        print(f'https://www.facebook.com/{pageID}/videos/{video_id}')
except:
    pass
files.clear()

os.remove(r"Output/ImagestoVideo/1616 Mackinac Dr. Crowley.mp4")
```